# Catching segfaults in C

Tags: c, macos, error-handling, segmentation-fault

I have a program that segfaults from pointer arithmetic sometimes. I know this happens, but I can't easily check ahead of time to see whether it segfaults or not - either I can "pre-scan" input data to see if it will cause a segfault (which can be impossible to determine), or I can refit it to not use pointer arithmetic, which would require a significantly larger amount of work, or I can try to catch a segfault. So my question:

1) How, in C, can I catch a segfault? I know *something* in the OS causes a segfault, but what can a C program do in the event that it segfaults to die a bit more gracefully than just `Segmentation fault`?

2) How portable is this?

I imagine this is a highly unportable behavior, so if you post any code to catch a segfault, please tell me what it works on. I'm on Mac OS X but I'd like my program to work on as many platforms as it can and I want to see what my options are.

And don't worry - basically all I want to do is print a more user-friendly error message and free some `malloc()`ed memory, and then die. I'm not planning on just ignoring all segfaults I get and plowing ahead.

Comment: Print the error message; don't free the memory, as the chances are decent that your memory system is scrambled when the seg fault happens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to define a signal handler.  This is done on Unix systems using the function [`sigaction`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/sigaction.html).  I've done this with the same code on Fedora 64- and 32-bit, and on Sun Solaris.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the function *signal* to install a new signal handler for the signal:

```
   #include <signal.h>
   void (*signal(int signum, void (*sighandler)(int)))(int);
```

Something like the following code:

```
signal(SIGINT , clean_exit_on_sig);
signal(SIGABRT , clean_exit_on_sig);
signal(SIGILL , clean_exit_on_sig);
signal(SIGFPE , clean_exit_on_sig);
signal(SIGSEGV, clean_exit_on_sig); // <-- this one is for segmentation fault
signal(SIGTERM , clean_exit_on_sig);

void 
clean_exit_on_sig(int sig_num)
{
        printf ("\n Signal %d received",sig_num);
}
```

Comment: ...noting that by the time you've got to a SEGV - where a pointer read/write just *happens* to have hit inaccessible memory - it's quite likely it's already managed to stomp over allocated, accessible memory, containing your data and the free block list.  So don't expect alloc to work, and don't expect any data in memory to be sane.

Answer (score 5):

The safe actions in a signal handler are **very** limited.  It's unsafe to call any library function not known to be re-entrant, which will exclude, for example, `free()` and `printf()`.  Best practice is to set a variable and return, but this doesn't help you very much.  It's also safe to use system calls such as `write()`.

Note that in the two backtrace examples given here, the `backtrace_symbols_fd()` function will be safe because it uses the raw fd directly, but the call to `fprintf()` is incorrect, and should be replaced by a use of `write()`.

Comment: Wow, that's rough. I'll keep these Draconian rules in mind. Maybe I really SHOULDN'T be trying to catch the segfault...

Comment: I certainly agree with the other comments suggesting that the right thing to do is fix the bug causing the segv.

Answer (score 1):

signal handling is (relatively) portable across unix machines (this includes mac and linux). The big differences are in the exception detail, which is passed as argument to the signal handling routine. Sorrty, but you will probably need a bunch of #ifdefs for that, if you want to print more reasonable error messages (such as where and due to which address the fault happened) ...

ok, here is a code fragment for you to start with:

```
#include <signal.h>

/* reached when a segv occurrs */
void
SEGVFunction( SIGARGS )
{
     ...
}

...
main(...) {
    signal(SIGSEGV, SEGVFunction); /* tell the OS, where to go in case... */
    ...
    ... do your work ...
}
```

Your task is to:

- check what SIGARGS is (OS dependent, so use an ifdef)
- see how to extract fault-address and pc from the exception information in sigArgs
- print reasonable message
- exit

in theory, you could even patch the pc in the signal handler (to after the faulting instruction), and proceed. However, typical signal handlers either exit() or to a longjmp() back into a save place in the main.

regards